# Read in XML in order with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to read an XML file in order but can't.

In fact I have an XML like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookings>
    <booking>
        <Id>424242</Id>
        <Number>01010101</Number>
        <info>
            <color>blue</color>
            <height>1</height>
        </info>
    </booking>
    <booking>
        <Id>9999</Id>
        <Number>777</Number>
        <info>
            <color>black</color>
            <height>2</height>
        </info>
    </booking>
</bookings>
```

Actually i use an XSL like this one below :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Id|Number|color|height</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bookings"/>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bookings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="booking"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="booking/info"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="booking">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
    <xsl:value-of select="color"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="height"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So i excpected this output:

```
Id|Number|color|height
424242|01010101|blue|1
9999|777|black|2
```

but got :

```
Id|Number|color|height
424242|01010101|9999|777|blue|1
black|2
```

Anyone got the solution or maybe a link where i can learn how to do it ? Because i don't find with my friend google.

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do here is move the apply-templates selecting `booking/info` into the template matching `booking` (and select only `info`)

At the moment, you are listing all bookings first, and then list all info elements.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Id|Number|color|height</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="bookings"/>     
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="bookings">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="booking"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="booking">
    <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="info">
    <xsl:value-of select="color"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="height"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/bookings">
    <xsl:text>Id|Number|color|height&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="booking">
        <xsl:value-of select="Id"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="info/color"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="info/height"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `<xsl:apply-templates select="booking/info"/>` changed to `<xsl:apply-templates select="info"/>` into the template for `booking`. Or simply make sure you use `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in any template where you need to process child nodes in the document order.